# Azure App Service Usage

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-app-service-plans, azure-app-service-envrmnt

I have deployed my **web service** in   **microsoft azure** as App Service(**Basic B1**). recently i observed that i was not using entire **resources(CPU,Memory)** in Basic B1 . so i decided to scale down my resources(CPU,Memory).

i know that **Shared** is the next low plan to **Basic B1**. But i need more **Resources(CPU,Memory)**  than **Shared** plan  is providing.

My Questions Are

1) is there any intermediary plan between (**Basic B1**) and **Shared**.

2) Why Azure is not costing based on the amount of the resources what i have used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) No. The tier below Basic B1 is Shared.

2) You are reserving capacity from a host. You are billed based on that. This way if your app should need more CPU/memory, it already has it available.

Comment: what  you said is correct. but what about  **AWS lambda**? they are costing based on the amount of resources web service uses. Isn't there equivalent in Azure ??

Comment: Azure Functions

Comment: Tq for your quick response how can i use Azure Functions to deploy my web service??

Comment: This might help: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-first-azure-function

Comment: the same code i have written for my web service is sufficient ?  do i need to rebuild entire web service to support Azure Functions ?

Comment: That is a very broad question. I suggest you look at the services offered to decide which would work for your app.

Comment: Thank you very much @junnas i will try to explore on the services they are providing